# SCP getting hang

Tags: linux, bash, unix, expect, scp

While executing the below code. the script gets hanged. /var/backups/archives/ contains about 3 files with around 5GB in size. It copies the first file and scripts hangs.

```
spawn scp -rp user@10.10.234.1:/var/backups/archives/ /var/backup
expect "user@10.10.234.1's password:"
send "password\n"
expect eof
if [catch wait] {
    puts "failed"
    exit 1
}
exit 0
```

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.ex` and see if there's anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'll see `expect: timed out` when you run your script with `expect -d`.

Insert `set timeout 60` in a new line after `send "password\n"`. Replace `60` with a number greater than the transfer time (in seconds) of **all** files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

i added set timeout -1 before spawn and it started working.